# How to create a docker file for libpostal (Address Parser) library?

Tags: python, docker, machine-learning, computer-vision

I have created a project in which I have used [lipostal](https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal) library. I have successfully installed it locally. Now, I want to deploy my flask API. I have created the following DOCKER file for that purpose.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV LIBPOSTAL_VERSION   v1.0.0
ENV LIBPOSTAL_DIR       /app/libpostal
ENV LIBPOSTAL_DATA_DIR  /app/libpostal_data
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        git \
        make \
        curl \
        autoconf \
        automake \
        libtool \
        pkg-config
RUN apt-get install wget
RUN wget https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal/archive/$LIBPOSTAL_VERSION.tar.gz
RUN mkdir -p $LIBPOSTAL_DIR
RUN tar -xvzf $LIBPOSTAL_VERSION.tar.gz -C $LIBPOSTAL_DIR --strip 1
RUN apt-get -y install sudo
RUN cd $LIBPOSTAL_DIR && ./bootstrap.sh && \
    mkdir -p $LIBPOSTAL_DATA_DIR && \
    ./configure --datadir=$LIBPOSTAL_DATA_DIR && \
    sudo make && \
    sudo make install && \
    sudo ldconfig
RUN apt-get install g++


#WORKDIR /app
#RUN cd $LIBPOSTAL_DIR && git clone https://github.com/openvenues/pypostal.git 
#RUN python setup.py build_ext --inplace
#RUN    pip install postal   
# We copy just the requirements.txt first to leverage Docker cache
#COPY ./requirements.txt requirements.txt

#RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
# CMD [ "python", "./app.py" ]
```

After running this docker file, I am getting the following **error**:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vtt2cf3x/postal_1bc597fd2b5947779d99465632b4fa6c/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vtt2cf3x/postal_1bc597fd2b5947779d99465632b4fa6c/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-yhakdb8i
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-vtt2cf3x/postal_1bc597fd2b5947779d99465632b4fa6c/
  Complete output (37 lines):
  /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:691: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
    warnings.warn(
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/postal
  copying postal/normalize.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/postal
  copying postal/parser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/postal
  copying postal/token_types.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/postal
  copying postal/tokenize.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/postal
  copying postal/dedupe.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/postal
  copying postal/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/postal
  copying postal/near_dupe.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/postal
  copying postal/expand.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/postal
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/postal/utils
  copying postal/utils/omitted.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/postal/utils
  copying postal/utils/enum.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/postal/utils
  copying postal/utils/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/postal/utils
  copying postal/utils/encoding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/postal/utils
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/postal/tests
  copying postal/tests/test_parser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/postal/tests
  copying postal/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/postal/tests
  copying postal/tests/_test_near_dupes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/postal/tests
  copying postal/tests/test_expand.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/postal/tests
  copying postal/pyutils.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/postal
  running build_ext
  building 'postal._expand' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/postal
  gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.8 -c postal/pyexpand.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/postal/pyexpand.o -std=c99
  postal/pyexpand.c:2:10: fatal error: libpostal/libpostal.h: No such file or directory
   #include <libpostal/libpostal.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for postal
```

I have tried many things, but nothing seems to work. It would be great if someone can help me out.